# how to find missing objects in a video using python

Tags: python, computer-vision

I have a stream from a webcam going into a linux pc. I have it pointed at 5 objects which are always in the same locations in front of the camera. I would like to know if one of the objects is missing. I tried to use opencv's absdiff but there is too much noise. Eventually it claims that the whole scene changed , even though nothing at all changed. Is there another (ideally python) way of comparing images?

Comment: [dummy way] If the objects have always the same color, you can simply check if the  pixels color in that location is changed or not (with opencv take the frame and check the color if changed or not in the pixels matrix).

Comment: Do you have a video where you are sure all of the objects are in the scene? If you do, you can model each pixel not as one value but as a distribution and then use the abs diff to check how likely the pixel is different then the expected value